# How do I serialize/deserialize object that implements interface/parent's methods

Tags: angular, typescript, serialization, deserialization

Is there a library that can do this or what is the best way to do it myself?

I tried this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/serializer.ts but it doesn't work properly because I have to explicitly specify the class via a decorator `@Type(() => Choice) myChoices: Choice[];` and after deserialization, it logically crashes with 'do is not a function'
I have:

```
abstract class Choice {
 public abstract do(): void; 
}

class Choice1 extends Choice{
 // some vars...
 public do(): void{
 console.log("do choice1");
} 
}

class Choice2 extends Choice{
 public do(): void{
 console.log("do choice2");
} 
}

class MyApp{
 public myChoices: Choice[];  
}
```

And there might be even more nested objects. How do I serialize/deserialize it?

Comment: It's unclear what problems you have with serializer.ts library. If you have specific problems with it, consider asking about them or opening an issue. Asking for libraries or 'the best way' is generally considered off-topic because this results in unspecific question. There's another thing that does this, https://github.com/dhlab-basel/json2typescript , if it helps.

Comment: I have a specific problem that when I'm trying to serialize and then deserialize the object I'm losing whatever the type it does have(It can be either Choice1 or Choice2). I guess the only option I have is to manually rebuild every object from a json string?

Comment: I assume that deserialize is expected to be called at some point, it should take care of nested class instances as well. Did you do that? Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I call deserialize but it can only assign the parent's type('Choice') because I have to explicitly specify what type of object I'm trying to deserialize via a decorator @Type. I assume it has the same problem in your link(@JsonProperty)

Comment: Of course, you need to specify classes for the whole chain, how would the thing otherwise know which classes correspond to these props?